# angularJS $apply causing RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, runtime-error

The $apply seem to be triggering the RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded and I have no idea why? Any insight would be useful..

```
data = d3.json("orgChartDataSMALL.json",function(error, data){

    if(error) throw error;
    $scope.$apply(function(){//Setting up data for stratification by indicating what will be the parent and children nodes

      stratify = d3.stratify()
                    .id(function(d) {return d.FullName;})//Position
                    .parentId(function(d) {return d.Manager;});//Manager's position

      rootPrep = stratify(data); //Transforming linear data into hierarchical data

      //Data needs slight remapping before feeding it into tree layout.
      rootPrep.each(function(d) {

        d.name = d.id; //transferring name to a name variable
        d.id = i; //Assigning numerical Ids
        i++;
        /*Calculating the numbers of employe under managers*/ 
       d.headcount = getDescendants(d); 
      }); 

      $scope.root = rootPrep;

    });

  });
```

Here is the getDescendant function but I don't see how this could be the cause of the error!

```
function getDescendants(node) {
          if(!node.children && !node._children) {
              return 0;
          }
          var total = 0;

          if(node.children){
              node.children.forEach(function(d) {
              total += 1+getDescendants(d);
            })
          }else if(node._children){
              node._children.forEach(function(d) {
              total += 1+getDescendants(d); 
            })
          }

          return total;
      }
```

Comment: At which line does the error occur?  Do you have any recursive function calls (I'm thinking getDescendants might)?

Comment: It happens on the line with $scope.$apply, and yes the getDescendant is a recursive function I added it to the bottom of the post @Mark

Comment: Do not wrap your code inside `$scope.$apply(fn); Try just `$scope.$apply();` before  `stratify = d3.stratify() ...`

Comment: @TheGreenFoxx Tried that I still get the same error. If I put the $apply() before the stratify nothing happens but if I put it after the $scope.root I still get the same error...